# Random Underlines in QT Program

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, qt, mnemonics

I found that almost all QT programs have the problem.  For instance, VLC

[image]

**OS:** Arch Linux
**QT version:** 5.12.1-2

**Questions:**
- Why there are so many random underlines in qt programs?
- How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Underlines in Menu bars denote shortcuts. ctrl-m will open the Menu and ctrl-t will open the subtitle menu.

It is simply a visual aid to quickly determine keyboard shortcuts.

[You can turn them off in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97413-turn-off-underline-access-key-shortcuts-menus-windows-10-a.html)

Not sure about Arch Linux.